# Is there a way to create a virtual drive in Ubuntu that contains multiple NTFS partitioned drives?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shortcuts, symbolic-link, ubuntu-unity

I have a dual boot set up (win 8/ubuntu 12.04) and in Ubuntu all 5 of my windows drives show up individually on the Unity launcher. It takes up a lot of space but I like being able to link directly to the drive.

One solution may be to create some shortcuts but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution working off of the nice Unity launcher interface.

In Windows, I am able to have each drive linked to the explorer right click menu for quick selection. Is something like this doable in Ubuntu off of the home folder icon or a custom icon?

Comment: You want the list of partitions to appear in the file browser right click menu? When you right click on what?

Comment: On an icon within the Unity launcher, either the home folder icon (desirable) or a custom icon.

Comment: It sounds to me like the solution you're looking for is a custom Unity icon (which, mind you, I don't know how to do), not a "virtual hard drive". Is that accurate?

Comment: My thought was that there may be two or more routes to essentially solve my problem. Creating a virtual drive that effectively has all real drives mapped under it would be sufficient while utilizing Unity would be more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good resource if you wanted to get into the code: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI

> Quicklists
>
> There are two kinds of Quicklists: the static ones which are always
>   shown once on right-click from the launcher entry and dynamic ones
>   which are only displayed once the application is started.
>
> Static Quicklist entries
>
> Adding a Static Quicklist entry is very easy, all you need is to add
>   some support to the desktop file. This is based on the desktop file
>   formats Action Groups.
>
> Here is what needs to be added to gnome-screenshot to support
>   Quicklist
>
> […]  Actions=Screen;Window;
>
> [Desktop Action Screen] Name=Take a Screenshot of the Whole Screen
>   Exec=gnome-screenshot OnlyShowIn=Unity;
>
> [Desktop Action Window] Name=Take a Screenshot of the Current Window
>   Exec=gnome-screenshot -w OnlyShowIn=Unity;
>
> Actions is referencing a Desktop Action. Each Desktop Action
>   references an item entry in the Quicklist. Here, we have the "Screen"
>   and "Window" entries, corresponding to :
>
> [Desktop Action entry]
>
> Then, each group have:
>
> ```
> a Name=, which is the entry as it's displayed which should be in title case.
>
> an Exec= referring a command line to execute once clicked. Details on additional syntax.
>
> OnlyShowIn=Unity is recommended to tell "show that entry in the Unity Springboard Quicklist" so that the file can be given upstream
> ```
>
> without the possibility of showing up in other untested desktop
>   environments. Please let upstream projects decide if they want to have
>   this action shown more widely.
>
> In the desktop spec there is a full desktop file sample with actions.
>   Here is an example of a patch for gnome-utils using the old X-Ayatana
>   style, but shows how to format the patch, with links to ubuntu bug and
>   forwarded upstream.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a module or something that allowed customized icons to be easily created using the API as a back-end.